# Is the primitive of a density function Hölder continuous?

Tags: analysis, probability-distributions, holder-spaces

Let $I=[-1,1]$ and let $f\in L^1(I)$.

Is it true that the function $F:I\to\mathbb{R}^+$ defined as
$$F(s)=\int_{-1}^s |f(x)|dx$$
belongs to $C^{0,\alpha}(I)$ for a certain $\alpha>0$?

Answer (score 0):

For $j=1,2\dots$ let $\delta_j=2^{-j^2}$. Define $$c_j=\delta_j^{-1+\frac1j},$$
$$I_j=(0,\delta_j)$$ and $$f=\sum_1^\infty c_j\chi_{I_j}.$$ Since all the terms are non-negative, for every $\alpha>0$ we have $$F(\delta_j)-F(0)=F(\delta_j)\ge\int_0^{\delta_j}c_j=\delta_j^{1/j}\ne O(\delta_j^\alpha).$$

Comment: I am looking for an $\alpha$ depending on $f$. So, fix $f$, there exists an $\alpha$ such that the primitive is Hölder?

Comment: You can construct an $f$ such that no $\alpha$ works by starting with what I did, splicing together the $f_\alpha$ above...

Comment: The example does not work for an $\alpha(f)$. Note that the primitive should be $t^{\alpha/2}$ which is Hölder for $\alpha^*=\alpha/2$

Comment: @DomènecRuiz Not sure what your point is; I thought I'd acknowleged that I wasn't claiming that $F_\alpha$ was in no Holder class; my only point was the weaker statement that $F_\alpha\notin Lip_\alpha$.

Comment: @DomènecRuiz Ok, I put it all together for you